# make behavior of components independent

Tags: reactjs

I am using reactJS.

I have a component `AnswerButtons`which is a group of toggle buttons like:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
const answers = [
    { point: 1, text: 'Answer one' },
    { point: .25, text: 'Answer two' },
    { point: .1, text: 'Answer three' },
    { point: 0, text: 'Answer four' },
]

const handleClick = (e) => { //This function simply enables toggling only one button at same time
    if (e.length === 0)
        setValue([])
    else if (e.length === 1) {
        setValue(e);
    } else {
        if (e[0] === value[0])
            setValue([e[1]])
        else
            setValue([e[0]])
    }
}

//This renders a group of 4 toggle button, 'question' is given by props
<h2>{question}</h2>
<ToggleButtonGroup type="checkbox" value={value} onChange={handleClick}>
        {answers.map((element, idx) =>
            <ToggleButton key={idx} id={idx} value={idx}>
                {element.text}
            </ToggleButton>)}
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

So, I am calling that component to render a quizz :

```
const questions = [] //list of questions

<div>
    {questions.map((q, idx) => 
        <AnswerButtons key={idx} question={q.text}} />)}
</div>
```

So my problem is that whenever I toggle a button of one question, it affects only the first rendered question.

Does any body know how I can fix that please?

Comment: can you please add a working demo : cidesandbox.io and explain in more detail what your expected behavior should be?

Comment: in `handleClick` if you `console.log(e)` then what gets logged?

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal an array containing the index of active toggleButtons, for example `[0]`, `[0, 1]`. The index goes to 3, because there are 4 buttons

Comment: and, `<ToggleButtonGroup type="checkbox" value={value} onChange={handleClick}>` value could be `[0]` or say  `[0,3]` ? So, `[0]` means only the first button is active while `[0,3]` means the first and last button are active, correct?

Comment: @Michael here is the code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-chatterjee-cfclv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal you're right, but in the `handleClick` I remove the previous activated button from the array. If my array is `[0, 3]` and it was `[0]` before, I remove it from the array. So the result is `[3]` at the end of the function.

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal please feel free to check the codesanbox link I shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the from the id.

```
<ToggleButton
                    size="sm"
                    key={idx}
                    variant="outline-success"
                    id={idx + question}
                    value={idx}
                  >
```

Comment: if only one answer can be selected probably can use radio box?

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much Jerry, was struggling on that problem. I just discovered that the problem came from `ToggleButton` but didn't get the problem. I am not using radio box because it's kind of ugly to me.